# Why do the paper sizes returned by libcups not match the paper sizes returned by lpoptions?

Tags: cups

**Quick summary**: The paper sizes returned by `lpoptions` look like
"w154h64", but the paper sizes returned using the libcups API look
like "custom_54.19x22.27mm_54.19x22.27mm".

**Note**: This is on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, with CUPS 2.3.1.

When I use `lpoptions` to get the paper sizes of my DYMO LabelWriter
450 Turbo printer, this is what I get.  (Output wrapped for clarity.)

```
$ lpoptions -p LabelWriter-450-Turbo -l
PageSize/Media Size: w154h64 w72h154 w72h72 w162h90 w54h144 w118h252
w167h188 w79h252 w167h252 *w167h288 w154h198 w82h248 w154h64.1
w79h252.1 w102h252 w154h286 w154h198.1 w54h424 w131h221 w57h248
w54h144.1 w72h72.1 w72h72.2 w162h90.1 30334_2-1_4_in_x_1-1_4_in w73h86
w72h154.1 w118h252.1 w54h203 w54h180 w36h136 w72h108 w65h90 w167h288.1
w168h252 w144h169 w71h144 w144h252 w80h144 w162h504
30383_PC_Postage_3-Part w167h540 30384_PC_Postage_2-Part w167h756
30387_PC_Postage_EPS w167h188.1 w176h292 w167h288.2 w112h126 w79h252.2
w102h252.1 w154h286.1 w154h286.2 w154h198.2 w63h419 w139h221 w36h144
w108h539 w167h539 w154h7680 w154h792 Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Resolution/Output Resolution: *300dpi 300x600dpi
DymoHalftoning/Halftoning: Default *ErrorDiffusion NLL
DymoPrintDensity/Print Density: Light Medium *Normal Dark
DymoPrintQuality/Print Quality: *Text Graphics
```

I would like to be able to get the same list of paper sizes
programmatically using the libcups API.  I wrote this program, which
gets the paper sizes two different ways.  (`cupsFindDestSupported` and
`cupsGetDestMediaByIndex`)  These two ways agree with each other, but
are completely different than what I get with `lpoptions`.

Program:

```c
/* Compile with:
 * gcc -o media `cups-config --cflags` media.c `cups-config --libs`
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cups/cups.h>

int print_dest(void *user_data, unsigned unused_flags, cups_dest_t *dest)
{
    if (dest->instance)
        printf("%s/%s\n", dest->name, dest->instance);
    else
        puts(dest->name);

    cups_dinfo_t *info = cupsCopyDestInfo (CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest);

    if (cupsCheckDestSupported(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest, info,
                               CUPS_MEDIA, NULL)) {
        ipp_attribute_t *media =
            cupsFindDestSupported(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest, info,
                                  CUPS_MEDIA);
        int i, count = ippGetCount(media);

        puts("media supported:");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i ++)
            printf("  %s\n", ippGetString(media, i, NULL));
    }

    unsigned flags = 0;
    cups_size_t size;
    int i;
    int count = cupsGetDestMediaCount(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT,
                                      dest, info,
                                      flags);

    printf ("count = %d\n", count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        if (cupsGetDestMediaByIndex(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest, info,
                                    i, flags,
                                    &size)) {
            const char *loc =
                cupsLocalizeDestMedia (CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest, info,
                                       flags, &size);
            printf("  %s:\n", size.media);
            printf("     Local: %s\n", loc ? loc : "N/A");
            printf("     Width: %.2fin\n", size.width / 2540.0);
            printf("    Length: %.2fin\n", size.length / 2540.0);
            printf("    Bottom: %.2fin\n", size.bottom / 2540.0);
            printf("      Left: %.2fin\n", size.left / 2540.0);
            printf("     Right: %.2fin\n", size.right / 2540.0);
            printf("       Top: %.2fin\n", size.top / 2540.0);
        }
    }

    return (1);
}

int main(void)
{
  cupsEnumDests(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE, 1000, NULL, 0, 0, print_dest, NULL);

  return (0);
}
```

Output of this program:

```
LabelWriter-450-Turbo
media supported:
  custom_54.19x22.27mm_54.19x22.27mm
  custom_25.4x54.02mm_25.4x54.02mm
  custom_1x1in_1x1in
  custom_2.25x1.25in_2.25x1.25in
  custom_0.75x2in_0.75x2in
  custom_41.32x88.9mm_41.32x88.9mm
  custom_58.67x66.04mm_58.67x66.04mm
  custom_27.86x88.9mm_27.86x88.9mm
  custom_58.67x88.9mm_58.67x88.9mm
  custom_58.76x101.6mm_58.76x101.6mm
  custom_54.02x69.85mm_54.02x69.85mm
  custom_28.62x87.29mm_28.62x87.29mm
  custom_35.73x88.56mm_35.73x88.56mm
  custom_54.02x100.84mm_54.02x100.84mm
  custom_19.05x149.27mm_19.05x149.27mm
  custom_46.06x77.81mm_46.06x77.81mm
  custom_19.9x87.29mm_19.9x87.29mm
  custom_25.74x30.14mm_25.74x30.14mm
  custom_19.05x71.46mm_19.05x71.46mm
  custom_0.75x2.5in_0.75x2.5in
  custom_12.7x47.67mm_12.7x47.67mm
  custom_1x1.5in_1x1.5in
  custom_22.86x31.75mm_22.86x31.75mm
  custom_58.93x88.9mm_58.93x88.9mm
  custom_50.8x59.52mm_50.8x59.52mm
  custom_24.81x50.8mm_24.81x50.8mm
  custom_2x3.5in_2x3.5in
  custom_27.94x50.8mm_27.94x50.8mm
  custom_2.25x7in_2.25x7in
  custom_58.76x190.5mm_58.76x190.5mm
  custom_58.76x266.7mm_58.76x266.7mm
  custom_61.89x102.87mm_61.89x102.87mm
  custom_39.29x44.45mm_39.29x44.45mm
  custom_22.01x147.66mm_22.01x147.66mm
  custom_49.02x77.81mm_49.02x77.81mm
  custom_0.5x2in_0.5x2in
  custom_38.02x189.99mm_38.02x189.99mm
  custom_58.76x189.99mm_58.76x189.99mm
  custom_54.02x2709.33mm_54.02x2709.33mm
  custom_54.02x279.4mm_54.02x279.4mm
  custom_min_3.53x3.53mm
  custom_max_56.9x2709.33mm
count = 40
  custom_12.7x47.67mm_12.7x47.67mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.50in
    Length: 1.88in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_0.5x2in_0.5x2in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.50in
    Length: 2.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.04in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_0.75x2in_0.75x2in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.75in
    Length: 2.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_0.75x2.5in_0.75x2.5in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.75in
    Length: 2.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_19.05x71.46mm_19.05x71.46mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.75in
    Length: 2.81in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_19.05x149.27mm_19.05x149.27mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.75in
    Length: 5.88in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.04in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_19.9x87.29mm_19.9x87.29mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.78in
    Length: 3.44in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_22.01x147.66mm_22.01x147.66mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.87in
    Length: 5.81in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_22.86x31.75mm_22.86x31.75mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.90in
    Length: 1.25in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.07in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_24.81x50.8mm_24.81x50.8mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 0.98in
    Length: 2.00in
    Bottom: 1.19in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.06in
  custom_1x1in_1x1in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.00in
    Length: 1.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.09in
  custom_1x1.5in_1x1.5in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.00in
    Length: 1.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_25.4x54.02mm_25.4x54.02mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.00in
    Length: 2.13in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.09in
  custom_25.74x30.14mm_25.74x30.14mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.01in
    Length: 1.19in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.06in
  custom_27.86x88.9mm_27.86x88.9mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.10in
    Length: 3.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_27.94x50.8mm_27.94x50.8mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.10in
    Length: 2.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.12in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.31in
  custom_28.62x87.29mm_28.62x87.29mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.13in
    Length: 3.44in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.20in
  custom_35.73x88.56mm_35.73x88.56mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.41in
    Length: 3.49in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_38.02x189.99mm_38.02x189.99mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.50in
    Length: 7.48in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_39.29x44.45mm_39.29x44.45mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.55in
    Length: 1.75in
    Bottom: 0.25in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.13in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_41.32x88.9mm_41.32x88.9mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.63in
    Length: 3.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_46.06x77.81mm_46.06x77.81mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.81in
    Length: 3.06in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_49.02x77.81mm_49.02x77.81mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 1.93in
    Length: 3.06in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_50.8x59.52mm_50.8x59.52mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.00in
    Length: 2.34in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_2x3.5in_2x3.5in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.00in
    Length: 3.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.12in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.37in
  custom_54.02x69.85mm_54.02x69.85mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.13in
    Length: 2.75in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_54.02x100.84mm_54.02x100.84mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.13in
    Length: 3.97in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.21in
  custom_54.02x279.4mm_54.02x279.4mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.13in
    Length: 11.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_54.02x2709.33mm_54.02x2709.33mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.13in
    Length: 106.67in
    Bottom: 0.24in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.07in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_54.19x22.27mm_54.19x22.27mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.13in
    Length: 0.88in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.06in
  custom_2.25x1.25in_2.25x1.25in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.25in
    Length: 1.25in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.04in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.06in
  custom_2.25x7in_2.25x7in:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.25in
    Length: 7.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_58.67x66.04mm_58.67x66.04mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 2.60in
    Bottom: 0.24in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.07in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_58.67x88.9mm_58.67x88.9mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 3.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_58.76x101.6mm_58.76x101.6mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 4.00in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.23in
  custom_58.76x189.99mm_58.76x189.99mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 7.48in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_58.76x190.5mm_58.76x190.5mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 7.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_58.76x266.7mm_58.76x266.7mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.31in
    Length: 10.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.06in
     Right: 0.04in
       Top: 0.22in
  custom_58.93x88.9mm_58.93x88.9mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.32in
    Length: 3.50in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.08in
       Top: 0.37in
  custom_61.89x102.87mm_61.89x102.87mm:
     Local: N/A
     Width: 2.44in
    Length: 4.05in
    Bottom: 0.06in
      Left: 0.00in
     Right: 0.20in
       Top: 0.37in
```

What is going on, and how can I get the list of paper sizes as
reported by `lpoptions`?  (Other than by shelling out to `lpoptions`
and parsing the results.)

Thanks!